# Are there any confirmed instances of Qrow's Semblance in action?

Tags: rwby

In *RWBY* Vol.4, we learn that Qrow Branwen's Semblance makes him a "bad luck magnet" - misfortune befalls anyone within close physical proximity to him. I haven't finished Vol.5 yet, but I can't think of any examples of this actually happening - pretty much all of the heroes' misfortunes so far have been caused by the villains.

**Were any on-screen events in the first five volumes directly affected by Qrow's Semblance?** To avoid making this speculative, I'm ideally looking for instances that were confirmed as such by Rooster Teeth themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yup.**

Remember, during the Vytal festival when we were first introduced to Qrow, how some poor barman broke a glass? Man, not his lucky day, between this and the drunken weirdo who was here like a minute ago... Hey, wait!

---

Other than that, Volume 4 Chapter 7 "Punished" is pretty much self-explanatory. Qrow sees an almost broken wooden plank (13'33, timestamped below), brings Tyrian around it, and seconds later it breaks. Oh, and Ruby was almost killed by another falling wooden plank (14'45, same episode).

As for instances confirmed by Rooster Teeth, in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/RWBY/comments/7x3w4s/crwby_ama_w_miles_luna_kerry_shawcross_and_paula/du5bpdm/?context=3) (warning: season 5 spoilers), Kerry Shawcross (co-writer and co-director from Volume 3 onwards, and voice actor for Neptune) explained that Qrow can choose to boost his bad luck semblance, in a fight for instance. So yeah, that definitely states that Tyrian breaking that roof was Qrow's doing.

> M&K: Does Qrow’s semblance constantly cost him aura or are passive semblances different in that regard?
>
> KERRY SHAWCROSS: It's not necessarily constantly running, it's more that it randomly spikes to cause unfortunate situations. If he chooses to amplify it in a fight, then yes, it does cost him.
>
> TOALHIKAN: So Qrow has some amount of control over his Bad Luck...Interesting...

[image: screenshot of Kerry Shawcross Reddit interview]

---

Some may argue that there are other instances (Winter getting caught by Ironwood during her fight with Qrow, among others), but I think they are less relevant.